# My celery.scheduler doesn't work which i use in my python app

Tags: python, redis, cron, celery

I have problem with running periodic task ? When I run the code celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=debug. It seems good but it stops and doesn't  do anything after this message in terminal:
[2019-07-10 22:29:21,149: DEBUG/MainProcess] basic.qos: prefetch_count->16

```py
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from datetime import date, timedelta
from config import *
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import smtplib
import ssl
import os

app = Celery('main', broker='redis://localhost')
app.conf.timezone = 'Asia/Bishkek'


@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(30.0, send_archives(), expires=10)

@app.task
def send_archives():

    yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)

    if len(os.listdir('archives')):
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['Subject'] = 'Archives for ' + yesterday.strftime('%d_%m_%Y')
        msg['From'] = EMAIL_HOST_USER
        msg['To'] = EMAIL_HOST_RECEIVER

        for filename in os.listdir('archives'):
            with open(os.path.join('archives', filename), 'rb') as attachment:
                part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
                part.set_payload(attachment.read())
                encoders.encode_base64(part)
                part.add_header(
                    "Content-Disposition",
                    f"attachment; filename={filename}",
                )
                msg.attach(part)
            os.unlink(os.path.join('archives', filename))

        context = ssl.create_default_context()
        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_PORT, context=context) as server:
            server.login(EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)
            server.sendmail(EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_RECEIVER, msg.as_string())
```

Comment: To add the schedule task you have to run the beat. `celery beat`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `expires=10`. It is easy to misunderstand this parameter. What it does is it tells Celery "if you can't execute this task in 10 seconds, do not run it at all" (the task "expires").

So, every 30 seconds you send the task to your Celery cluster. If the task runs for longer then 30 seconds, your queue will become full, and many tasks that get scheduled after that will simply expire.

Even worse - if for whatever reason your task reaches a condition when it blocks forever, such tasks can fill the queue, and no other tasks will run.

Comment: This is not help to me. Celery still does not do anything (

Comment: You have few options: 1) create more workers 2) make the task less frequent 3) improve it so it never blocks for a long time (if it does)